# Override Mapbox Studio minzoom

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

I've styled some census tract tilesets and set filters in Mapbox Studio, where everything looks fantastic, but I want the tracts to appear shaded irrespective of the zoom level, and Studio won't let me set a minzoom lower than 8.  I've tried changing the minzoom after load in javascript:

```
map.setLayerZoomRange ('ba_percent', 4, 22)
```

And I see the change reflected if I log

```
map.getLayer('ba_percent')
```

But that doesn't affect what appears in the browser.  There must be a way to show census tract data at whatever zoom level I choose, right?  Just for reference, this is how the map looks when tracts are shaded.

[image]

Comment: What is the source of your census tract data? It is possible that there are settings that cannot be overridden.

Comment: geoJSON files from censusreporter.org.  I'm not an expert at reading geoJSON files, but it just looks like a few properties and then geometry for each tract.

Comment: The geoJSON file likely has only data to a certain extent, if you wanted to see things at any extent, you would likely need to grab the raw data from the census database and create a js file from that yourself.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize it worked that way.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am not 100% sure how your JSON files are being created, but here is a little background on ArcGIS and why there is a need to limit the amount of data someone can pull at a time from the server, if you are interested: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/open-data/provider/server-configuration-details.htm

Comment: Makes sense.  I have shapefiles from the census already uploaded, maybe I'll just try to programmatically address those layers based on the geoJSON data.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this: I used [Tippacanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) to change the zoom limits on my existing geoJSON file.  You just have to be careful of your settings or you'll end up with enormous files.